# Publish core3.1 web application

Tags: web-deployment-project, asp.net-core-3.1

when I publish my core 3.1 web application in a folder by frameworck dependent mode, the size of the folder generated was 125 MB ... it is huge in addition to the classic asp.net application.
i have many folder ("cs", "de", "es" "fr" ect...), dll like Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll (5 MB) and other...
in my {assembly name}.DEPS.json file i have all dependency... the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll was referenced but i dont used in my application!!!
where does this file come from?
and how unrefenced this dll?
and how can i reduce my publish folder?

Answer (score 3):

At the time of publishing there is a option to produce a single file you can do it by choosing file option. By this size also decrease in which your only single file is publish.

[image]

Comment: I make my publication with visual studio 2019 and i dont have this option...

Comment: ahhh I found this option but it is in the case of a self-contained publication...I want make a publication frameworck depending...

Comment: now i see it :) ...and generate a single file very good... but when i deploye in IIS i have : Application DLL not found. Confirm the application dll is present. Single-file deployments are not supported in IIS.what going on?

Comment: Okay it clearly says that single file is not supported in IIS but if my answer helps you a little bit please upvote. Also there is no way to publish single file on IIS right now MS not supported this feature.